# Disable clicking in spinbox python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project where I need to be able to adjust stock in a python Tkinter program, to do this I am using a spinbox which allows the program to know how many items the user wants to add or subtract. I have the `from_` and `to` set to values but I can't figure out how to stop the user clicking in the field and changing the value to something outside of the range manually.

I am fairly new to python so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When you define your spinbox, just set argument `state` to `"readonly"`. Example:

```
w = Spinbox(master, from_=0, to=10, state = 'readonly')
```